# Why some emails don't have a header string?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I have 10's of GBs of emails stored in Microsoft Exchange and copies of them with me as public folders.

When I checked this, most of them don't have email headers, why is it like that ?

Also some of the headers are unable to be parsed (particularly the ones having 'Microsoft Mail Internet Headers Version 2.0' at the beginning). Why?

Answer (score 1):

PT_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS property is only populated for the messages received from the internet. Message sent between two Exchange mailboxes in the same domain do not have that property.

"'Microsoft Mail Internet Headers Version 2.0" line was added by old versions of Outlook (before 2003?). Latest versions of Outlook do not insert that line.